# Литература по Fuzzing

Tags: тестирование

Подскажите подробное руководство по этому методу тестирования.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другие учебные материалы по тестированию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451404/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я в свое время завис, читая http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bart/fuzz/*

*Также неплохой кусок обзора fuzz фреймворков есть на хабре - http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/code_review/128503/*

Вообще говоря, `fuzz-based` тестирование - это, конечно, забавная штука, но, по моему личному мнению, абсолютно бессмысленная на всех проектах малого и среднего размера, да и сам по себе метод *(как некоторый статистический подход)* слабо оправдывает затраты на внедрение и постоянную интерпретацию результатов.

---

Также это напоминает вероятностный подход для определения количества ошибок в коде *(правда, здесь это относится лишь к входным данным, но все же)* - мол, давайте внесем в исходный код `N` преднамеренных ошибок, затем произведем поиск ошибок по всему коду, которых мы обнаружим ровно `M` и на основании этих данных по вероятностной модели предположим общее количество оставшихся ошибок.

Теоретическая модель правильная, математически обоснованная, но за время, пока ты с ее помощью добьешься более-менее значительных результатов в продакшене **можно 3 раза покрыть весь код юнит-тестами.**

*То же самое часто происходит и с fuzz-тестами, особенно в неумелых руках.*

Comment: Вот поэтому и хочу научится, прежде чем применять)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что английский язык не является большой помехой :)

[руководство](http://taviso.decsystem.org/fuzz.html)

Comment: ну уже хоть что то, хотя было бы не плохо более серьезную литературу почитать